# Shorthand assignment operator for inverting boolean

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator, shorthand

There are shorthand operators for the basic arithmetic operators, such as:

```
x = x+2;
x += 2;
```

or

```
y = y*2;
y *= 2;
```

However, I was wondering if there was any such operator that could simply invert the value of a boolean.

For example, assuming `z = true`, is there any shorter equivalent to:

```
z = !z;
```

I know it can't be just `!z`, because then it would just return the opposite value of `z`, but it wouldn't change its value.

I know I'm kind of lazy, but I use this a lot in my code and am trying to optimize it as much as possible. I'd try to avoid repeating variable names as much as possible to keep it cleaner and more elegant.

Also, I'm coding in JavaScript.

Comment: `z=!z` is the same number of characters as `y*=2`. How much shorter were you hoping to get it?

Comment: c'mon man! ...  2 extra characters is too much of a chore? Create a keyboard shortcut if it's too much work

Comment: @charlietfl Longer with a longer variable name =P ... but I was just wondering if there was any shortcut at all. I like brevity.

Comment: well how hard is it to look up *"javascript operators"* in mdn docs and see for yourself

Comment: @charlietfl I couldn't find anything there, so I came here to SO to ask in case I had overlooked something.

Comment: My personal favorite method of inverting a boolean is `z = !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!z;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would just negate the thing the way you've done it. But if it really matters to you, and you can afford to forgo the `boolean` type, just use the numeric internal representation (true==1, false==0) and bitwise operators to negate it:

```
z = true;  // z is type boolean
z ^= 1;    // z is now false, but its type is number
           // (z == false) evaluates to true and you can still do things like if (z)...
z ^= 1;    // z is now true again
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I didn't think of bitewise operators.